# Amazon payment in Magento 2.3 error

Tags: magento2, amazon

I have amazon payment method in my shop, used Magento 2.3

If it's sandbox mode, it's ok. But live mode, it show this error. Please help me, thanks all

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Magento\Eav\Model\Attribute\Data\Text::validateLength() must be of the type string, null given, called in /home/public_html/vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Attribute/Data/Text.php on line 80
```

Comment: It seems like Magento's known issue https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/23588 and will be fixed in latest Magento upgrade.